# Can radar detect dumb bombs in freefall mode?

Tags: projectile, radar

Can gravity bombs dropped from an aircraft be detected by radar and intercepted with a missile to prevent detonation on ground impact? Is there currently such a system?

Edit: Its a military/defence question but cant find any relevant tags for this.

Comment: Sea Sparrow has intercepted 5-inch shells in trials.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could of course detect and shoot the bombs. It is even easier to do than with anti-tank missiles because you will not have any noise from the ground. The issue is why you would do that?

Unlike the case of the anti-tank missiles where you protect small target against one shell with modern free-falling bombs you need to counter four scenarios:

1. Area bombing with large numbers of bombs. You need to shoot down many targets over large area. Why instead not to invest in SAMs to shoot down the bomber rather than into an anti-bomb defense systems with dubious effectiveness?
2. Low altitude bombing with very large number of small bombs. Again it is much easier to shoot the bomber rather than large number of bombs individually.
3. Low altitude bombing of important targets like airstrip with few bombs. It becomes more sensible though why not to shoot down the much larger and much more expensive bomber before it drops the bombs when it's in a rather vulnerable position?
4. Large tonnage bomb. If you shoot it at low altitude it's likely to have the same effect as if you didn't shoot it at all. If you shoot it higher... Why not shoot down the bomber???